# How To add Linebreak on specific characters in django?

Tags: html, django

I Want To add Linebreaks after specific characters but i don't know how to do that!

Here is the image

[image]

Look at this image i want to add line breaks after 50 characters

Here is my **HTML FILE**:

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container mt-3">
    <h3>{{ post.title }}</h3>
    <hr>
    {% if post.blog_img %}
        <div class="card-image" style="background-image: url({{ post.blog_img.url }}); height: 370px;background-size: cover;background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center center;"></div>
        <hr>
    {% endif %}
    <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
    <hr>
    <p>About <a href="{% url 'category' slug=post.category.slug %}">{{ post.category.name }}</a> By <a href="{% url 'profile' username=post.author.username %}">{{ post.author.username }}</a> Posted At: <strong>{{ post.timestamp|timesince }}</strong></p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Here is my **views.py**

```
def detail(request,slug=None):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post,slug=slug)
    if post.status == 'published':
        context = {'post':post,}
        return render(request,'blog/detail.html',context)
    else:
        return redirect(index)
```

Comment: You can do `word-wrap` using css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `wordwrap` filter. [From the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#wordwrap):

Wraps words at specified line length.

Argument: number of characters at which to wrap the text.

For example:

`{{ value|wordwrap:5 }}`

If value is Joel is a slug, the output would be:

```
Joel
is a
slug
```